# PHP - Dynamically reference object function

Tags: php

I'm not sure if this is possible, but i'm trying to dynamically call a function in my `Test` Class called `Dropdown()`

i am able to dynamically reference my `public $Store;` variable, by doing this.

```
$model=new Test;
$lol = 'Store';
echo $model->{$lol};
```

But when i try to call the function `Dropdown()` in my class, i get an error `Property "Test.Dropdown()" is not defined.`

```
$model=new Test;
$lol = 'Dropdown()';
echo $model->{$lol};
```

How would i dynamically call a function in my Test class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$model->{$lol}()` to call that method:

```
$className = 'Test'; //additional dynamic class call, if needed example for that too.

$class = new $className();
$method = 'Dropdown';
$class->{$method}();
```

Comment: works! but why `$class->{$method}();` and not? `$class->{$method}.'()';` ?

Comment: @user2636556 Because you are calling method and when you append `.'()'` to method name, it's not valid constant. Inner PHP things.

Comment: Because `$class->{$method}.'()'` will attempt to retrieve the value from the __property__ of `$class` called `$method`, and then append `'()'` to that value

Answer (score 0):

You can use function [`call_user_func()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) or [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) like this:

```
class Test {
    public function Dropdown($text) {
        echo($text);
    }
}

$class  = 'Test';           // class name
$method = 'Dropdown';       // only the method name, the '()' is part of the PHP syntax
$param  = "Hello world\n";  // parameter

call_user_func([$class, $method], $param);
```